# Why did Reagan look like a zombie?

Tags: dc, batman, dark-knight-returns-2012

In Dark Knight Returns part II, President Reagan is seen several times commanding "Him" (Superman). It shows him as a greenish, pasty guy.

[image]

Why did they portray Reagan like that?

Comment: I added an image for reference, but, having never seen the show I cannot tell if it is correct. If it is not accurate or helpful, please roll the edit back.

Comment: Might be trying to keep it close the novel.

Comment: I know that they are trying to be accurate, but I never read the novel. And I still don't know why they would portray him like that.

Comment: @xantec yeah that's Reagan from the movie.

Comment: [He looked a lot worse in the original book](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lg9jngZQRK1qz8hy0o1_500.jpg)

Comment: The screenshot above is strongly green-tinted - *everything* is greenish and pasty, in order to mark it as a TV broadcast

Comment: Don't know if it helps or not, but Reagan being referred to as having a zombie-like appearance isn't necessarily restricted to Batman; both Family Guy and The Simpsons have had "Zombie Reagan" as spoofs as well. And, from what I can tell, all three are creepily accurate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a caricature, and a deliberate one.  I don't pretend to know Miller's politics, but I suspect he wasn't a big fan.

There's an element of satire in the Dark Knight Returns series.  Miller caricatured a number of mid-80s celebrities and politicians: Reagan, David Letterman ("David Endochrine"), Dr. Ruth, etc.  His caricature of Reagan was savage, but no more so than most editorial cartoonists of the time.

Then again, the Dark Knight Returns series was supposed to take place, well, right around *now* (i.e., 20 to 30 years after 1986), so if Reagan was still President (ignoring that whole 22nd Amendment thingy), he'd be well over 100 years old and probably looking a touch zombie-ish.

**EDIT**

Well, maybe not "well over" 100; Wednesday was his 102nd birthday.

Comment: Any day after your 36,500th that you're still breathing counts as doing "well". ;)